# Use char16_t type as an array of char[] and reconvert it via reinterpret_cast<>. Does my code have undefined behavior?

Tags: c++

I want to check the object memory representation of the `char16_t` type as an array of `char[]` and reconvert it via `reinterpret_cast<>`. Does my code have undefined behavior?

My conversion code is as follows:

```
char16_t code;

..... // some operating ensure the variable 'code' keep a value

for (auto rbegin = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code + 1), rend = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code); rbegin != rend;)
    fout.put(*(--rbegin));
```

My main question is whether `reintepret_cast<char*>(&code +1)` is wrong? At the same time, can I do this?

Comment: Why is the question tagged C? This is clearly C++. In any case, this code is fine. Using `char*` to step through the bytes of an object is well-defined behavior in the C++ standard. There is explicit language in the standard to allow this kind of use-case.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to add C++, but I chose C...

Comment: `code` is not an array, so what do you expect `&code + 1` to be?

Comment: This solution is naive in regard to [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  On some architectures, the character, say, 0x1234 will be `fout.put` as 0x12 then 0x34, others 0x34 then 0x12.

Comment: You need to add 1 *after* you cast to `char *`. Remember `*(p + 1)` is equivalent to `p[1]` is `p` is a pointer.

Comment: @P.W，I want to get the end position of the 'code' memory representation，because I want to put(it) in reverse, in the form of char

Comment: @Glxandsf: Then you can do what I have suggested in the answer.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz in this example, adding 1 before the cast is the correct thing to do to get a pointer to the address after the variable. Adding 1 after the cast will get the address of the variable's 2nd byte instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`code` is not an array of `char16_t`s (although it can be considered as an array of 1 element). So dereferencing `&code + 1` will result in undefined behavior as you are accessing out of bounds.

Instead you can do the following which is safe:

```
rbegin = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code) + 1
```

Since `reinterpret_cast<char*>(&code)` will result in a pointer to `char`, adding 1 to that means you are still within the limits of memory you are allowed to access. (I am assuming here that `char16_t` has two bytes).

Comment: For purposes of pointer arithmetic, any variable of `T` is treated as if it's an 1-element array of `T`. Therefore `&code + 1` forms a one-past-the-end pointer, which is valid to evaluate, but UB to dereference.

Comment: thanks，I wanted to use this solution for the first time, but I thought of this solution after thinking about the the 'end' position of 'code', but I am not sure if the solution after using the 'end' is undefined, so I raised this question.

Comment: @milleniumbug:Yes, I have clarified the answer by replacing "trying to access it" with "dereferencing it".